# Select subdomains using print command

Tags: linux, awk, sed, printing, command

`cat a.txt`

```
a.b.c.d.e.google.com
x.y.z.google.com
```

```
rev a.txt | awk -F. '{print $2,$3}' | rev
```

This is showing:

```
e google
x google
```

But I want this output

```
a.b.c.d.e.google
b.c.d.e.google
c.d.e.google
e.google
x.y.z.google
y.z.google
z.google
```

Comment: Do have more fields or your file is exactly the same? if its not then edit your question with samples and let us know then, cheers.

Comment: `awk -F. 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{print $1,$2}' a.txt `  does the job, `cat` isn't necessary

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Edited Fully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828930/select-subdomains-using-print-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="."
}
{
  nf=NF
  for(i=1;i<(nf-1);i++){
    print
    $1=""
    sub(/^[[:space:]]*\./,"")
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: You could just use `sub(/^[^.]*\./,"")` instead of `$1=""; sub(/^[[:space:]]*\./,"")` and then you don't need to set `OFS` either as you'd no longer be using it.

Comment: Thank you so much sir I need this same
thank you again

Comment: Done sir, -----

Comment: Hello @RavinderSingh13 Please look this sir
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866686/grep-aws-s3-buckets-from-url-source-code

Comment: hello @RavinderSingh13, i don't remove your answer it's work very well, i just add another answer as accepted because that one is simple and easy and also no need to create separate .sh file.
But i also appreciate your work to solve my problem
THANK YOU

Comment: i'm new here so i don't know that what is the effect on your profile after accepting another answer by me

Comment: @Shin, It has reduced 15 points from my profile but its up to you which one you want to accept, completely.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 
**what is the uses of this cmd**
`cat file.txt | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/\.js.*/.js/'`

Comment: @Shin, Looks to me its deleting blank lines and then its substituting .js followed by amything with .js(this is exact translation of your code shown), in case you have more questions related to your any input and expected output then request you to kindly open a new question and we could discuss there, cheers.

Comment: Thank You, but i don't understand 2nd part (sed 's/\.js.*/.js/')
I ask this question here bcoz, i already submitted quetion so can't submit another after 90mintus so.
now i ask other questions in new questions

Comment: @Shin, yeah I explained both parts together, this second part substitute from .js till end of line with only .js cheers

Answer (score 4):

Here is one more awk solution:

```sh
awk -F. '{while (!/^[^.]+\.[^.]+$/) {print; sub(/^[^.]+\./, "")}}' file

a.b.c.d.e.google.com
b.c.d.e.google.com
c.d.e.google.com
d.e.google.com
e.google.com
x.y.z.google.com
y.z.google.com
z.google.com
```

Comment: Thank You sir, I appreciate your work to solve my question.

Comment: what if there is a - in some subdomains such as
`www-name-string.sub.domain.com`

here i want this output
`com
domain.com
sub.domain.com
string.sub.domain.com
name-string.sub.domain.com
www-name-string.sub.domain.com`

Comment: `www-name-string` is considered one part not 3 in a domain name. Only dot is considered a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En 'p;:a;s/[^.]+\.(.*([^.]+\.){2}[[:alpha:]]+$)/\1/p;ta' input_file
a.b.c.d.e.google.com
b.c.d.e.google.com
c.d.e.google.com
d.e.google.com
e.google.com
x.y.z.google.com
y.z.google.com
z.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash:

```
IFS=.
while read -ra a; do
    for ((i=${#a[@]}; i>2; i--)); do
        echo "${a[*]: -i}"
    done
done < a.txt
```

Gives:

```
a.b.c.d.e.google.com
b.c.d.e.google.com
c.d.e.google.com
d.e.google.com
e.google.com
x.y.z.google.com
y.z.google.com
z.google.com
```

(I assume the lack of `d.e.google.com` in your expected output is typo?)

Comment: Thanks for answer, and sorry but it's not working for me,
I found my answer in other answers

Answer (score 1):

For a shorter and arguably simpler solution, you could use Perl.

To auto-split the line on the dot character into the `@F` array, and then print the range you want:

```sh
perl -F'\.' -le 'print join(".", @F[0..$#F-1])' a.txt
```

`-F'\.'` will auto-split each input line into the `@F` array. It will split on the given regular expression, so the dot needs to be escaped to be taken literally.

`$#F` is the number of elements in the array. So `@F[0..$#F-1]` is the range of elements from the first one (`$F[0]`) to the penultimate one. If you wanted to leave out both "google" and "com", you would use `@F[0..$#F-2]` etc.